# How to fix these errors so I can finally use 'webdriver.Chrome()'?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to essentially "click" a button on a webpage using python. I am trying to use the selenium package (as seen in this example [how_can_i_essentially_click_a_button_on_a_webpage/](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6bt8g2/how_can_i_essentially_click_a_button_on_a_webpage/)) but then I get the following message right after running the code:

I really don't understand what's going on.
I would appreciate any help if possible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browsre = webdriver.Chrome()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    browsre = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Your issue is `chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into

> 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

it seems that your script is not able to find the `chromedriver.exe` under [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so you need to [add the folder, containing the `chromedriver.exe` to your system PATH](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

[image]

If you're running your test via [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) you can do the same in Run/Debug configurations:

[image]

and last, but not the least, you can amend the driver initialization line to contain the full path to your `chromedriver.exe`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
```

References:

- [Selenium Webdriver using Python: Tutorial with Example](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-python.html)
- [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python)

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your chromedriver.exe located? Is it located in the path that is specified in yours tests?

Try this in your code:

```
 browser = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, could you please accept this as an answer? (Click the 'check' icon beside the answer)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way. Thanks anyway